# Media query fails for only one property

Tags: media-queries

I am unable to change padding for one element on mobile devices. The queries are working for several properties, but padding will not work (neither will line height if I try to use that). Basic styling in custom css is:

```
#topright {
font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
    padding-top: 8px !important;
    padding-bottom: 8px !important;
    font-weight: 200;
}
```

Media query for phone is

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
 @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
        .header-2 .logo  {
    width: 250px;
    }   
    .footer-widget ul li {
            width: 100%;
    }
    .footer-widget ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    }
    div.vc_column-inner vc_custom_1476556729591 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    }
    .footer-widget .textwidget p {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #topright {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px
    }   
}
```

The smaller padding number will not be applied. If I remove !important from main css, then the phone query gets applied to all devices. It's weird because all the other properties for the phone query are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

From [this helpful page](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width) on media queries, `min-width: 320px` means:

```
"If [device width] is greater than or equal to 320px, then do {...}"
```

In other words, the media query you think you created to target only iPhone will actually be firing for all devices which have a width of 320px or *greater*.  Instead, I think you intended to use `max-width`

So use this CSS:

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    .header-2 .logo  {
        width: 250px;
    }   
    ...
    #topright {
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 1px
    }
}
```

And you should also remove the `!important` directives from your `main.css` file.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much!

Comment: Please mark correct if it solved your problem, thanks.